# How to make VS Code recognize .class file?

Tags: java, visual-studio, class

I'm trying to use VS Code with java, but I have an issue.
As a student, my teacher gives me a file named *Clavier.class*.
I have already wrote a programm with another IDE, and when I execute it in the command of Windows, it works without any problem. But, when I put this programm in VS Code, it doesn't recognize *Clavier.saisirInt*, which is a static method in *Clavier.class*. I guess that VS Code can't use a class which is in a File.class, but is there a way to make it works ?

Here is an image of my workspace and you can see the error at the bottom

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `lib/` folder is placed onto the execution classpath. If this is the case, that's where compiled class files should go, not next to your sources

Otherwise, you'll need to inspect the `java` command that actually runs your code to see what/if the `-cp` argument is set to, or include those class files similar to how the [documentation shows for JAR files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_library-configuration) (which are just zipped packages of class files, and honestly what the teacher should provide instead)

> By default, VS Code will reference all JAR files in workspace's lib directory using the glob pattern `lib/**/*.jar`

And so, you need to adjust this to include `lib/*.class` after moving your files there

Comment: I think that the problem is that the file is already compiled. For example, the file Purse is well recognized by the Main but not the file Clavier when they're all in the same folder. I can't understant why the file in well executed on the Windows terminal, or other IDE like Replit or SciTe but VS code can't do that.

Comment: It doesn't matter if code is already compiled. As answered, you need to adjust your execution classpath. I'm not sure what command you're using on the terminal, but by default the classpath includes the current folder. The IDE execution of the `java` command may, and often does, override that

Comment: I already tried to create a new java project from VS code, put my main class and Purse class in "src" and put Clavier.class in lib, and it doesn't worked. You told that I need to adjust my execution class path, but what I don't know how to do that. I'm sorry, I never used a real IDE before so I don't understand yet all technical terms.

Comment: The documentation I linked to says what settings in Vscode to adjust